# Java Pass-by-reference not working?

Tags: java, variables, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to make this little game in Java but I seem to have stumbled upon a variable reference problem.
My Entity class, which Player extends from, keeps a variable of type Dimension.
This Dimension gets set via the constructor of the Entity class like so:

```
protected Dimension dimension;

public Entity(Dimension dimension) {
    this.dimension = dimension;
}
```

In my player class, this is how I pass the dimension object via his constructur:

```
public Player(Dimension dimension) {
    super(dimension);
}
```

I also have a Game class, which keeps all the possible dimensions, plus an extra variable called activedimension which keeps a reference to the active game dimension.

```
private Dimension activedimension;
private Dimension overworld;
private Dimension otherdimension;

public Game() {
    overworld = new OverWorldDimension();
    otherdimension = new OtherDimension();
    activedimension = overworld;
}
```

When I want my overworld dimension to reset, I use this method:

```
public void resetOverWorld() {
    overworld = new OverWorldDimension();
    activedimension = overworld;
}
```

Now, whenever I call this resetOverWorld method from anywhere, it seems like my activedimension really did refresh, but the dimension stored in my Player/Enitity class didn't.
I'm fairly new to Java, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with the variable-references being passed through constructors and methods.
My application seems to copy a dimension object somewhere instead of passing the reference, but I can't figure out where.

Any help or thoughts are welcome.
Thanks in advance
~Krikke

Comment: Java is pass by value.  EDIT: And I don't see where you update the copy in the Entity/Player class.  Can you show that code please?

Comment: You are reassigning the reference that you passed. Imagine that you live at #5, you give everyone your address (passing the reference) and when they write to your address you get the post (calling method). Then you secretly move house without telling anyone. Where does your post go?

Comment: @Mike Java is never pass by reference. It passes references by value for objects.

Comment: @Kyle You are quite correct, I had my semantics wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't updating the reference in your `Player` class. When you store your `Dimension` in your `Entity` constructor you are storing a reference to that `Dimension` in memory. In your `resetOverWorld()` method you change the `overworld` and `activedimension` variables to point to a new `OverWorldDimension` but all the references elsewhere (e.g. your `Entity` objects) haven't changed. They still refer to the initial `Dimension` they were constructed with.

You might want to consider having a `DimensionTracker` class that your `Entity` could hold instead, allowing you to change it's internal `Dimension` from a single location. Otherwise you need to update every `Entity` to refer to the new `Dimension`.

```
public class DimensionTracker {
    public Dimension dimension;
    public DimensionTracker(Dimension d) {
        dimension = d;
    }
}
```

...

```
protected DimensionTracker dimensionTracker;

public Entity(DimensionTracker dt) {

    dimensionTracker = dt;
}
```

...

```
public Player(DimensionTracker dt){
    super(dt);
}
```

...

```
private DimensionTracker activedimension;
private Dimension overworld;
private Dimension otherdimension;

public Game() {
    overworld = new OverWorldDimension();
    otherdimension = new OtherDimension();
    activedimension.dimension = overworld;
}
```

...

```
public void resetOverWorld() {
    overworld = new OverWorldDimension();
    activedimension.dimension = overworld;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to figure out what was going wrong for a while now. This answer answers it all! Marked as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void resetOverWorld() {
    overworld = new OverWorldDimension();
    activedimension = overworld;
}
```

this will just update the Game class variable   `private Dimension activedimension ;`

after call to `resetOverWorld()`, you have to set this new reference to Entity class by doing something like

```
entity.setDimension(activedimension)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the reference to the variable overworld, but to value of overworld with this:

```
this.dimension = dimension;
```

So you have to update the reference for Entity manually when the reference changes in the game, else it will point to the old value since it's independent from the variable overworld.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a dimension object to your `Player` object, and it stores a reference to that object in one of its fields.

In your `Game` object you set `activedimension` to refer to a `Dimension` object. By changing its value you change it to refer to a different `Dimension` object.

Even if `activedimension` used to refer to the same `Dimension` object you passed to `Player`, changing it to a different `Dimension` object does not change which object is refered to in `Player`.

Consider, if the system starts like this:

```
Game
-  activedimension --> Dimension object A

Player
- dimension --> Dimension object A
```

Changes to `Dimension object A` will be seen by both the `Player` and `Game` objects.

However, changing `activedimension` to point to `Dimension object B`, a totally different object does not make `dimension` change to point to it.

```
Game
-  activedimension --> Dimension object A

Player
- dimension --> Dimension object B
```